Flutter - Execution failed for task
My other app's build is working fine. But this app build is giving me this issue how to solve this?
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode... Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug' .  > A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Users/navidrahman/ Developer/ flutter/ bin/ flutter' ' 
* Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle. org
BUILD FAILED in 15s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


Something is wrong with your set-up. The mentioned path /Users/navidrahman/ Developer/ flutter/ bin/ flutter contains multiple spaces which doesn't seem to be correct (or is this an error introduced by copy-and-paste the error message into the question?).

It's just a copy paste error!

Then please fix it. And next time please make sure to copy the unmodified error message into your question.
